# How to handle events in Material Design Light mdl-menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, material-design-lite

I am using Material Design Light without any other framework like Angular or android. Just plain old PHP, Jquery, MDL min css and js.
Simple menu

```
<button id="lang-switcher" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <i class="material-icons">language</i>
</button>
<ul id="lang-switcher-items" class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-menu--top-left" for="lang-switcher">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">EN English</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">RU Русский</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">UK Українська</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">PL Polski</li>         
</ul>
```

Menu item click must run js function like `setLanguage(language)`

How do i create listener for "mdl-menu__item" click? Should i use Jquery `.click(function())` for every `li`, or is any other ways for using `mdl-menu` like `select` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery's click event and bind it with the class. Also define an **ID** for your li elements so that you can get to know which element was clicked. look at the following example

```
$(".mdl-menu__item").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(id+"was clicked");
})
```

To demonstrate i have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtkacf1u/)

Comment: Catching the click does indeed work as shown - I just want to add that you can declare an additional parameter in the click handler to get the click-event container the element taht was clicked (instead of working with DOM-IDs)